# Cannot create Ejabberd MUC_ROOM from remote ip

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

First of all, sorry for my bad english

I'm currently trying to configure ejabberd to allow the admin user to execute commands from remote ip address. On my local PC, everything works because ejabberd is installed on the same PC.

Here is the `ejabberd.yml` for the production environment :

````
default_db: sql
registration_timeout: infinity

hosts:
    - xmpp.production_server.com

host_config:
  xmpp.production_server.com:
    sql_type: pgsql
    sql_server: "DATABASE_SERVER"
    sql_database: "DATABASE_NAME"
    sql_username: "DATABASE_USER"
    sql_password: "DATABASE_PASSWORD"
    sql_port: 10933
    sql_ssl: true
    auth_method: [external]
    extauth_program: "PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_SCRIPT_AUTH"
    extauth_instances: 3
    auth_use_cache: false

loglevel: 5
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

certfiles:
  - /home/ejabberd/conf/server.pem

ca_file: "/home/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

## When using let's encrypt to generate certificates
##certfiles:
##  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem
##  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem
##
##ca_file: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws

  -
    port: 8080
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws

  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000
s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  apicommands:
    user:
      - "admin": "xmpp.production_server.com"
    ip:
      - "0.0.0.0"
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@xmpp.production_server.com"
    ip:
      - "0.0.0.0"

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: admin
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access: admin

    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
      - mod_http_api
  "public commands":
    who:
      access: all
      ip: "0.0.0.0"
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number
      - send_message
      - create_room

shaper:
  normal:
    rate: 3000
    burst_size: 20000
  fast: 100000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:example-admin@example.com"
   ca_url: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  #mod_http_upload:
      #put_url: http://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: true
      persistent: true
    hosts:
        - conference.production_server.com
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  #mod_sip: {}
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8```

But when I try to create room or send_message to a specific room, I always get 403 error (for access denied).
````

Answer (score 1):

After many days of investigation, I found the issue was in the `api_permissions` section. In the "admin access" parts, you should explicitly add the acl keyword like
`-acl: admin`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are sending API queries to port 5443 or 8080, which are handled by mod_http_api

I configured similarly to you, but less lines (to grant less permissions):

```
api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "api calls":
    from:
      - mod_http_api
    who:
      ip:
        - 127.0.0.0/8
        - ::1/128
    what:
      - registered_users
      - send_message
      - create_room
```

That allows me to send queries like:

```
$ ejabberdctl connected_users_number
0
```

And this from local machine:

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:5280/api/registered_users?host=localhost
["admin","user1"]
```

In your case, you should add to that `ip` section the IP address of your remote machine, either IPv4 or IPv6, or both to be sure.